# starting watchKit extension causes SigKILL for IOS parentapp

Tags: ios, swift2, watchkit

when starting my watchKit app (on device or simulator) it causes SigKill on AppDelegate straight away.

(I did put breakpoints on Interface Controller viewDidLoad and ExtensionDelegate applicationDidFinishLaunching as well as on start of the variables declaration, but the crash is even before these are reached)

Any ideas?

Comment: I am facing the exact same issue with my SiriKit extension, were you able to solve this ?